# How do I prove cold wallet reserves?

Tags: transactions

For audit purposes I am trying to prove cold wallets reserves, is it possible to send a message with a USDT transaction or publicly 'label' a wallet?

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=4382780.0

Comment: thank you, given USDT is not compatible with Electrum, how would I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know about USDT, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't need to do something specific for USDT.

Your best bet would be to sign a message proving ownership of each address you hold USDT in. Once you prove you control the addresses, you can prove that you control the USDT balance at any given block height for those addresses using the signed messages and a node that can calculate the balances.

Comment: How is a USDT transaction signed?

Comment: A USDT transaction is just a Bitcoin transaction with a specifically formatted OP RETURN output - if you control the BTC address, you control the USDT. It is signed just like any other Bitcoin transaction